# How to take JavaScript url link to my index.php page

Tags: javascript, php

```
var feedback = function (res) {
    if (res.success === true) {
        var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
        document.querySelector('.status').classList.add('bg-success');
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML =
        'Image : ' + '<br><input class="image-url" value=\"' + get_link + '\"/>' + '<img class="img" alt="Imgur-Upload" src=\"' + get_link + '\"/>';
    }
};
```

The second portion is:

```
new Imgur({
    clientid: '3527680b6690575', //You can change this ClientID
    callback: feedback
});
```

How to `get_link` to php variable in a index.php page?

Comment: Can you please add more details with code?

Comment: The index.php is just a sample php page.

Comment: Full code is also here in this link. https://github.com/carry0987/Imgur-Upload

Comment: By ajax request ...

Comment: Could u please write some sample code about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is like this:

```
function notifvanish() {
    var data = 0;
    var dataset = 'set=' + data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "notifvanish.php",
        data: dataset,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            //alert("Success");
        }
    });
}
```